# Phpseclib sftp put runs out of memory with 1 GB+ files

Tags: php, phpseclib

I am trying to transfer large zip files using phpseclib's sftp [put](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/sftp/examples.html#put) method. Files under 1 GB or so transfer without any issue. However, larger files are failing soon after reaching the 1 GB mark during transfer.

I get this PHP error:

```
"PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 89653248) 
(tried to allocate 3717163274 bytes) in 
../lib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php on line 1553".
```

Code:

```
require_once('phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php');
require_once('phpseclib/Crypt/RSA.php');

$sftp = new Net_SFTP($host);
$key = new Crypt_RSA();
$key->loadKey(file_get_contents($privatekey));
$sftp->login($username, $key);

$sftp->put($remotefile, $localfile, NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE);
```

The memory_limit setting in my php.ini is set to -1. Are there any other PHP settings that could be causing this limitation? Or any settings in the phpseclib library that could help?

Comment: Are you on a 32bit PHP? You're trying to allocate 3.7gigs of ram. For various reasons, the most a 32bit program can ever allocate in a single block is ~3gig, depending on some OS tweaks and whatnot.

Comment: @MarcB that is a true statement, but not particularly helpful. A process for SFTP'ing a file should not need to read the whole thing into memory at once.

Comment: What version of phpseclib are you using?

Comment: @AndrewMedico: if you can think of a reason why a script that could stream 1meg at a time (or whatever) could possibly need 3.7gig of ram, feel free to enlighten us.

Comment: I *don't* think it should need that much memory, and I already said exactly that. My point is that stating "3.7 billion bytes = 3.7GB" does not help the OP figure out *why* the script is unnecessarily asking for so much memory.

Comment: @MarcB - It's running on 64bit PHP. phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php is version 1.21 and phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php is version 1.46.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running a super old version of phpseclib. The 1.21 / 1.46 versions that you're referring to are populated through the [CVS keyword $Id: $](http://www.badgertronics.com/writings/cvs/keywords.html) and phpseclib hasn't used CVS in years.

The last **release** version (as opposed to individual file commit version) of phpseclib that used those was 0.2.1 and the last commit for that version was in April 2010:

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/0.2.1/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php#L51

Contrast that with the 0.2.2 release which doesn't have the `CVS keyword $Id: $` stuff:

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/0.2.2/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php#L48

phpseclib is currently at 0.3.7. There have been 6 version releases since 0.2.1 (0.2.2, 0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.5, 0.3.6 and 0.3.7) so try [upgrading](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Upgrading to latest version of phpseclib seems to have fixed the issue. Magento EE 1.11 is packaged with that old version, so I was just trying to use what was already available.